# Is there a way of solving the gap-and-islands for date ranges ignoring weekends?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

My client has an attendance system that stores absence data in (approximately) this form (in other words, by single or half day):

```
EmployeeID   AbsenceDate   AbsenceDays
1            2020-06-25    1
1            2020-06-24    1
1            2020-06-23    1
1            2020-06-22    1
1            2020-06-19    1
1            2020-06-18    1
1            2020-05-25    1
1            2020-06-23    1
1            2020-06-22    0.5
```

I built a report that outputs this data "as is", but the client has asked if it could be of this form (with contiguous relevant days aggregated into a range with sum):

```
EmployeeID   StartDate   EndDate       NoOfDays
1            2020-06-18  2020-06-25    6
1            2020-05-22  2020-06-25    2.5
```

I have looked into the gaps-and-islands solution but the difficulty is that for both these there is an intervening weekend for which absence data should **not** be counted.  Is there any way of doing this using standard SQL (rather than using a cursor or other ROBAR solution which, for obvious reasons, I'd rather avoid).

Comment: One approach would be a calendar table to distinguish between business and non-business days.  But with an attendance system, you might have some employees that work weekends and holidays too. I think you ultimately need a way to identify the work schedule per employee before calculating absences.

Comment: What happened to 2020-06-24?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this kind of grouping can be done relatively easy on the client side using your classic programming language, not SQL. But, if you insist...

---

> I have looked into the gaps-and-islands solution but the difficulty is
> that for both these there is an intervening weekend for which absence
> data should **not** be counted.

The main idea is to generate the missing rows for all weekends with 0 value for `AbsenceDays`, so that gaps-and-islands would not create extra ranges when it goes over the weekend.

I would use the calendar table for this (a table with the list of all dates and various flags, such as `IsWeekend`).

Please note, that this approach would also return correct results even if there are some AbsenceDates that fall on the weekend.

**Sample data**

I have tweaked your sample data to make it more interesting and non-ambiguous. (Your example lists the same dates twice for the same `EmployeeID`)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (EmployeeID int, AbsenceDate date, AbsenceDays float);

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(2, '2020-06-25', 0.5),
(2, '2020-06-24', 0.5),
(2, '2020-06-23', 0.5),
(2, '2020-06-22', 0.5),
(2, '2020-06-19', 0.5),
(2, '2020-06-18', 0.5),
-- here we go across the weekend and both Sat and Sun are skipped

(1, '2020-06-25', 1),
(1, '2020-06-24', 1),
(1, '2020-06-23', 1),
(1, '2020-06-22', 1),
(1, '2020-06-19', 1),
(1, '2020-06-18', 1),
-- here we go across the weekend and both Sat and Sun are skipped

(1, '2020-05-25', 1),
(1, '2020-05-23', 1),
(1, '2020-05-22', 0.5);
-- here we go across the weekend and only Sun is skipped
```

**Query**

This query uses `Calendar` table with `dt` for all dates and a flag `IsWeekend`.

`CTE_Boundaries` calculates what range of dates we need from the calendar for each employee. `CTE_Weekends` gives us a row for each Sat and Sun. In the end we put together dates from the source table and from the calendar.

```
WITH
CTE_Boundaries
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,MIN(AbsenceDate) AS StartDate
        ,MAX(AbsenceDate) AS EndDate
    FROM
        @T AS T
    GROUP BY
        EmployeeID
)
,CTE_Weekends
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Boundaries.EmployeeID
        ,Calendar.dt AS AbsenceDate
        ,0 AS AbsenceDays
    FROM
        CTE_Boundaries
        INNER JOIN Calendar
            ON  Calendar.dt >= CTE_Boundaries.StartDate
            AND Calendar.dt <= CTE_Boundaries.EndDate
    WHERE
        Calendar.IsWeekend = 1
)
,CTE_AllDates
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,AbsenceDays
    FROM @T AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,0 AS AbsenceDays
    FROM
        CTE_Weekends
)
SELECT
    EmployeeID
    ,AbsenceDate
    ,SUM(AbsenceDays) AS AbsenceDays
FROM CTE_AllDates
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID
    ,AbsenceDate
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| EmployeeID | AbsenceDate | AbsenceDays |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|          1 | 2020-05-22  |         0.5 |
|          1 | 2020-05-23  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-05-24  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-05-25  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-05-30  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-05-31  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-06  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-07  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-13  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-14  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-18  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-06-19  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-06-20  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-21  |           0 |
|          1 | 2020-06-22  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-06-23  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-06-24  |           1 |
|          1 | 2020-06-25  |           1 |
|          2 | 2020-06-18  |         0.5 |
|          2 | 2020-06-19  |         0.5 |
|          2 | 2020-06-20  |           0 |
|          2 | 2020-06-21  |           0 |
|          2 | 2020-06-22  |         0.5 |
|          2 | 2020-06-23  |         0.5 |
|          2 | 2020-06-24  |         0.5 |
|          2 | 2020-06-25  |         0.5 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now you can apply gaps-and-islands to this dataset and you will get one group for dates `2020-05-22 - 2020-05-25` and `2020-06-18 - 2020-06-25`. You will also get groups for each weekend, but the sum of `AbsenceDays` for those lone weekends would be zero, so we can filter them out.

Here I used `ROW_NUMBER` to solve gaps-and-islands:

**Final query**

```
WITH
CTE_Boundaries
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,MIN(AbsenceDate) AS StartDate
        ,MAX(AbsenceDate) AS EndDate
    FROM
        @T AS T
    GROUP BY
        EmployeeID
)
,CTE_Weekends
AS
(
    SELECT
        CTE_Boundaries.EmployeeID
        ,Calendar.dt AS AbsenceDate
        ,0 AS AbsenceDays
    FROM
        CTE_Boundaries
        INNER JOIN Calendar
            ON  Calendar.dt >= CTE_Boundaries.StartDate
            AND Calendar.dt <= CTE_Boundaries.EndDate
    WHERE
        Calendar.IsWeekend = 1
)
,CTE_AllDates
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,AbsenceDays
    FROM @T AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,0 AS AbsenceDays
    FROM
        CTE_Weekends
)
,CTE_Data
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,SUM(AbsenceDays) AS AbsenceDays
    FROM CTE_AllDates
    GROUP BY
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
)

-- apply gaps and islands to CTE_Data
,CTE_RowNumbers
AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeeID
        ,AbsenceDate
        ,AbsenceDays
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY AbsenceDate) AS rn1
        ,DATEDIFF(day, '2020-01-01', AbsenceDate) AS rn2
    FROM
        CTE_Data
)
SELECT
    EmployeeID
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN AbsenceDays > 0 THEN AbsenceDate END) AS StartAbsenceDate
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN AbsenceDays > 0 THEN AbsenceDate END) AS EndAbsenceDate
    ,SUM(AbsenceDays) AS NoOfDays
FROM
    CTE_RowNumbers
GROUP BY
    EmployeeID
    ,rn2 - rn1
HAVING
    SUM(AbsenceDays) > 0
ORDER BY
    EmployeeID
    ,StartAbsenceDate
;
```

We need `CASE WHEN AbsenceDays > 0 THEN AbsenceDate END` for cases when the first or last `AbsenceDate` of a range is a Monday or Friday. Without this check the adjacent two days of the weekend may be appended to the final range.

**Result**

```
+------------+------------------+----------------+----------+
| EmployeeID | StartAbsenceDate | EndAbsenceDate | NoOfDays |
+------------+------------------+----------------+----------+
|          1 | 2020-05-22       | 2020-05-25     |      2.5 |
|          1 | 2020-06-18       | 2020-06-25     |        6 |
|          2 | 2020-06-18       | 2020-06-25     |        3 |
+------------+------------------+----------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't look right.  There are multiple rows per day.  I am guessing this is not really allowed, and these should probably be different employees.

To solve the weekend problem, you can use `lag()`, a cumulative sum, and some date arithmetic:

```
select EmployeeId, min(AbsenceDate), max(AbsenceDate), sum(AbsenceDays)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when datename(weekday, AbsenceDate) in ('Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') and prev_ad = dateadd(day, -1, AbsenceDate)
                      then 0
                      when datename(weekday, AbsenceDate) in ('Monday') and prev_ad = dateadd(day, -3, AbsenceDate)
                      then 0
                      else 1
                 end) over (partition by EmployeeId order by AbsenceDate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(AbsenceDate) over (partition by EmployeeId order by AbsenceDate) as prev_ad
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by EmployeeId, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23d345240baa52ce04df701ca07ab918) is a db<>fiddle.  The results look correct based on the sample data, but are different from your question.

Comment: Just a note. If some of the dates in the given dataset fall on Saturday or Sunday, this approach will return extra rows that could have been collapsed. OP didn't clarify in the question if such data is possible and what result should be in such case. OP would decide how significant it is.